# Making simple allowed array in PHP? (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have some simple function to collect allowed array, but something is not ok, can somebody help me? Here is my code

```
public function getAllbyLink($table, $what, $url)
{
   $link=mysql_real_escape_string($url);
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$what." = '{$link}' LIMIT 0 , 1");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
        else redirect('');
}
```

Comment: Please be specific about what is not "ok".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read something about MVC pattern, question is clearly pointed on how to write a Model.

consider using this function

```
public function getTable($table, $where = array(), $select = '*', $order_by = '', $limit = '', $offset = '') {

    if ($order_by !== '' && $order_by != 'RANDOM') $this->db->order_by($order_by);
    if ($order_by == 'RANDOM') $this->db->order_by('id', 'RANDOM');
    if ($limit !== '') $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $this->db->select($select);
    $q = $this->db->get_where($table, $where);

    return ($q->num_rows() > 0) ? $q->result() : FALSE;

}
```

for your purpose call the function like this:

```
getTable($talbe, array('what' => $link)); 
//returns FALSE if no data are selected, 
//or returns object with data,
```

if you wish return array instead replace `$q->result()` with `$q->array_result()`

Please note that active record auto escapes.

---

After comments:

comment-1, you can simplify that function easily just delete what you do not need, for example

```
public function getTable2($table, $where = array(),  $limit = '', $offset = '') {

    if ($limit !== '') $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $q = $this->db->get_where($table, $where);

    return ($q->num_rows() > 0) ? $q->result() : FALSE;

}
```

comment-2,when there is no data use this `if-else` statement

```
if (!$my_data = getTable2('table', array('where' => $link))) {
    //there is some DATA to work with
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($my_data);
    echo "</pre>";

} else {
    //no DATA do redirect or tell user that there is no DATA
    redirect(); //redirect to default_controller
}
```

comment-3, no comment;

comment-4, *It also allows for safer queries, since the values are escaped automatically by the system.* from this [source](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html). And another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12490093/1564365) about active record providing exact answer you are seeking.

Comment: Ok, this is most adnavced model, txansk, tell me just one thing, what will happen if there is wrong $what

Comment: Can you sow me example, what all i can put i construct, and to redirect  when there is no data, txanks in advance

Comment: Btw Question is not about that, it is about allowed array from table\

Comment: And there is no protection against mySql injection?

Comment: Hello, if you are using active record there is no such thing as sql injection, everything you are giving to the codeigniter native function is escaped. How can be $what wrong? If that happens codeigniter throws mysql error that there is no such column as $what. In other hand if $link is "wrong" model returns FALSE and you sure know that model returned no data what so ever. I will demonstrate on example (edit).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your code is:

- Read all rows from table
- Check if `linkurl` is in the list
- If so, return a random row for that value
- Else, redirect.

In this case, try this:

```
public function getAllbyLink($table,$url,$what)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("
          SELECT *
          FROM `".$table."`
          WHERE `".$what."` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($linkurl)."'
          ORDER BY RAND()
          LIMIT 1
    ");
    if( !$query) return redirect('');
    $result = $query->result();
    if( !$result) return redirect('');
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Consider your answer right and wrong, OP uses CodeIgniter and should use [active record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).

Comment: And just by the way: why did you use `ORDER BY RAND()` is it faster than just running it without it? or is it a typo? Thanks.